# how to pass parameters from Objective C to Swift within init

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, parameter-passing, init

In Apple sample code, iOS Metronome , https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/HelloMetronome/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017587

Now Apple hard code self.setTempo(120) with 120 at the end of following code.

```
override init() {
    super.init()
    // Use two triangle waves which are generate for the metronome bips.

    // Create a standard audio format deinterleaved float.
    let format = AVAudioFormat(standardFormatWithSampleRate: 44100.0, channels: 2)

    // How many audio frames?
    let bipFrames: UInt32 = UInt32(GlobalConstants.kBipDurationSeconds * Float(format.sampleRate))

    // Create the PCM buffers.
    soundBuffer.append(AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: format, frameCapacity: bipFrames))
    soundBuffer.append(AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: format, frameCapacity: bipFrames))

    // Fill in the number of valid sample frames in the buffers (required).
    soundBuffer[0]?.frameLength = bipFrames
    soundBuffer[1]?.frameLength = bipFrames

    // Generate the metronme bips, first buffer will be A440 and the second buffer Middle C.
    let wg1 = TriangleWaveGenerator(sampleRate: Float(format.sampleRate))                     // A 440
    let wg2 = TriangleWaveGenerator(sampleRate: Float(format.sampleRate), frequency: 261.6)   // Middle C
    wg1.render(soundBuffer[0]!)
    wg2.render(soundBuffer[1]!)

    // Connect player -> output, with the format of the buffers we're playing.
    let output: AVAudioOutputNode = engine.outputNode

    engine.attach(player)
    engine.connect(player, to: output, fromBus: 0, toBus: 0, format: format)

    bufferSampleRate = format.sampleRate

    // Create a serial dispatch queue for synchronizing callbacks.
    syncQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "Metronome")

    self.setTempo(120)
}
```

How to pass parameters, instead of hardcoded with 120, from Objective C 's following code to  above Swift code within init:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

NSLog(@"Hello, Metronome!\n");

NSError *error = nil;
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"AVAudioSession error %ld, %@", error.code, error.localizedDescription);
}

[audioSession setActive:YES error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"AVAudioSession error %ld, %@", error.code, error.localizedDescription);
}

// if media services are reset, we need to rebuild our audio chain
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(handleMediaServicesWereReset:)
                                             name:AVAudioSessionMediaServicesWereResetNotification
                                           object:audioSession];

metronome = [[Metronome alloc] init];
metronome.delegate = self;
```

}

thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a parameter to the Swift method, change

```
override init() {
...
self.setTempo(120)
```

to something like

```
init(frequency: Int) {
...
self.setTempo(frequency)
```

This will allow you to call your Objective-C init as

```
[[Metronome alloc] initWithFrequency: (your frequency)];
```

Regarding your sound problem, it's unclear what's going on without more context on what you're trying to do, but I would attempt to move your init code from viewDidLoad to viewDidAppear.

Comment: It still cannot work. initWithFrequency in [Metronome alloc] of Objective-C , but in swift part, your answer is init(frequency: Int). I tried to use initWithFrequency(frequency: Int) in Swift but failed. Please help. thanks. Sorry that sometimes here cannot reply in time because google service not available occasionally here.

Comment: Objective-C renames Swift inits, that's why it's different. Does it not show up in autocomplete?

Comment: It does not show up in autocomplete. When I write [[Metronome alloc] initWithFrequency: (240)]; by myself, the red error shows: No visible @interface for 'Metronome' declares the selector 'initWithFrequency:' BTW it's Swift Version 3 in this project. Thanks ! Your earlier reply will be appreciated.